# Standings gains from epic arcs?

Tags: eve-online

In EVE Online there are a variety of Epic Arcs - one for each faction, a sisters of EVE arc, and a couple of pirate arcs.

What reputation gains (corporate and faction) do I get from completing each arc? By completing the arc for a certain faction will I lose standards with other factions?

Would it be possible to complete all of the epic arcs and if so would the standings gains and losses result in a net gain or would I lose standing overall by doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The epic arc standings change percentages are listed on the official wiki [here](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Epic_mission_arcs).   The formula for standings change is also available on the same site, [here](http://wiki.eveonline.com/en/wiki/Standings_mechanics).  The standings gains would be calculated for the faction which offers the arc, and losses also depend completely on what is killed during missions and your current standings, due to the percentage based method of changing the standings.   The arcs can be completed every three months, if I remember reading that correctly on the official forums.

Comment: Both links are down. What I can't seem to find out no matter how much I research is, does the SOE epic arc give bonus to SOE standing, or only a faction standing?